# Back button to root navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using storyboard and have 3 VCs. When I'm on VC3 I would like the back button to skip VC2 and go to VC1.

I tried the following which works but VC2 flashes before I get to VC1

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

My custom back code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.backPressed(_:)))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black  
}

@objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){
    print("here")
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Comment: try using navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) when you press back in VC3.

Comment: Use an unwind segue

Comment: How do you push `VC3`? Using storyboard segue?

Comment: @Vikky how do I asign that piece of code to my back button?

Comment: Just write code in @IBAction of back button in your VC3. But I think you are using segue?.

Comment: @Paulw11 I cannot select the back button on my VC to Exit, it selects the full Navigation Bar.

Comment: You will need to use a custom back button and link that to the unwind segue.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR VC1 to VC2 is a button in the NavBar, VC2 to VC3 is a button and both segues are show/push.

Comment: @Vikky That's the weird thing, I cannot select the Back button in my NavBar to drag a IBAction, it selects the full NavBar.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you help with the code for the back custom button to unwind segue?

Comment: The answer below gives you the code to create the button.  You need to create an `@IBAction func unwind(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)` function in the view controller your want to segue to (There is no code in this function).  Then ctrl-drag from the view controller to the "exit" icon in the storyboard and select `unwind:`. Give the segue an identifier Now you can simply `performSegue()` that segue to unwind. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) is a little out of date since it uses Objective-C but the basic process is the same

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm already using the VC to Exit segue as my VC has a table and it's used to unwind to VC1 when a row is selected.

Comment: Ok. So all you need to do is trigger that segue from your custom back button

Comment: @Paulw11 Something like this? self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.backPressed(_:)))

Comment: Yep and in `backPressed` you simply perform the unwind segue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")

     var backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backPressed(_:)))
     navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black  
}
```

Add
if you want to go at very first controller use

```
@objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) 
}
```

and if its not fist view controller in navigation controller

```
@objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){
     let controllerToBeReached = navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourViewController }.first!
     navigationController!.popToViewController(controllerToBeReached, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Do I still use the viewWillDisappear function?


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }


This still creates a animation to VC2 before getting to VC1.

Should I be using something else to trigger that back button?

Comment: why doing in viewWillDisappear? You should be doing my code in action of back button of navigation controller

Comment: Is that done here? self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Comment: On UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.backPressed(:))) I get error (1)Expected expression in list of expressions (2) Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. On @objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){
         self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController
    } I get error (1) Expression resolves to an unused function

Comment: put _ before :    ...  colon and both error will disappear

Comment: Use like this 

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.backPressed(_:)))

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: That has cleared up the error but still getting one error (1) Expression resolves to an unused function on @objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){ self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController }

Comment: again updated my answer i dont know whats happening with me  
it should be 
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: No errors thanks. I placed a print("test") inside backPressed() but it is not triggering it.

Comment: I think it's because I have a custom button: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")

Comment: you have to post a  complete code in that condition because there are several things about your code we dont know ...

Comment: One More try let do it with target set to self too 

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backPressed(_:)))

Comment: I've added the full viewDidLoad with your code in original post.

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote answer so other one find it helpful :) it they require this too :)

Comment: Hi Abu, so I tried the other option, to move to a previous NV/VC but the code doesnt work.

    @objc func backPressed(_ sender: Any){
        //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        let UserNav = navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is UserDashboardVC}.first!;navigationController!.popToViewController(UserNav, animated: true)
    } I've verified my NC name "UserNav" and VC name UserDashboardVC. I get a Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to see VC2 flashed before VC1 appears, and in case VC1 is the root then just set `animated = false`

Override action back from your VC3 then use this: `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`

Answer (score 0):

In Your code back Button Automatically perform `popToViewController` first than `viewWillDisappear` method call so that you flashes on `VC2`

In VC3 add Back `BarButtonitem` for perform action for go to `VC3` to `VC1`

```
override func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton
    }
```

Here method of back `UIBarButtonItem`

```
@objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let vc = VC1()
    self.navigationController.popToViewController(vc, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: This works but kills my custom back button. self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_back")

Comment: if you want to use image in Back button use UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backPressed(_:)))

Comment: you don't need to use  backIndicatorImage or backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage in  because we use UIBarButtonItem navigationBar.